# MATLAB Optimization column access

Tags: matlab, optimization

I'm working on optimizing my code. I'm going through MATLAB's own optimization webpage (https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/programming-patterns-maximizing-code-performance-by-optimizing-memory-access.html) and writing code to makes sure I understand how to increase the performance. Point 2 suggests that when you store and access matrix data, do so with columns. However, I can't construct my own code that shows this performance boost. If i'm reading it right the two simple codes below should differ in performance by about 30%, however I'm getting far, far less than that:

```
x=zeros(10000);

tic

for i = 1:10000
    for j = 1:10000
        if x(i,j) == 0
            x(i,j)=randn(1);
        end
    end
end

toc

Elapsed time is 41.102294 seconds.

x=zeros(10000);

tic

for j = 1:10000
    for i = 1:10000
        if x(i,j) == 0
            x(i,j)=randn(1);
        end
    end
end

toc

Elapsed time is 39.654574 seconds.
```

Comment: Probably the multiple `randn`'s inside the loops takes a way more time than the half of second that you save with the column-wise operation

Comment: Yes, try to do something much simpler, like incrementing the value by 1.

Comment: 39 seconds vs 41 seconds look more like a ~5% performance increase to me. But the bottleneck here is due to the inner rand, not by the indexing.

Comment: This article was published in 2007 (see footnote). MATLAB's engine has been completely redesigned since then, with the introduction of the [new JIT compiler in R2015b](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/02/12/run-code-faster-with-the-new-matlab-execution-engine/), and now loops are interpreted in a much more efficient fashion. When running, these two examples *likely* both operate "under the hood" in the most efficient way regardless of the way you've written it.

Comment: @Wolfie I run the example in the second section from the link (in question), and I get about 60% improvement while column-wise. I use 2016a.

Comment: @Adiel Ah I didn't have a machine on hand to test. It's still always good practise to keep in mind how old a piece of writing on performance is, especially within the MATLAB sphere when it's updated every 6 months. Thanks for the info.